# Flow with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, attachments, flow, comments

I have a list where I'm running a workflow created on MS Flow. 
I am using "start and wait for approval action" for an approval process. 
But with the approval, I also want to give the feature of adding an attachment along with the comments to the approver who approves the task.

Can some one please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not achievable with OOB Flow since we cannot modify the approval progress to accept “Add attachment” action.

Plus, if the item is approved, it will trigger another content approval request when the approver modify the list item. If it is not approved, the approver won’t even have the ability to modify the item.

There are certain posts with similar suggestion in the Power Automate feedback forum. You can vote for the post below to help improving this product:

[Add attachment in FLOW Approval notification.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Add-attachment-in-FLOW-Approval-notification/idi-p/263559)